# How to write agda equivalent code of this coq code?

Tags: coq, agda

I want to write the given coq code in agda.

```
Definition included (D1 D2:R -> Prop) : Prop := forall x:R, D1 x -> D2 x.
```

I have tried in this way ..

```
data included (D1 D2 : R -> Set) : Set where
      forall x : R D1 x -> D2 x
```

I know the problem is in second line but how to fix it. Do we need to define constructor ?? And how will i do that??

please help.

Answer (score 3):

`data` in Agda is the equivalent of `Inductive` in Coq: it introduces a new type defined inductively.

The equivalent of `Definition` in Agda is simply a defining equation for the thing you wish to define:

```
postulate R : Set

included : (_ _ : R → Set) → Set
included D1 D2 = ∀ x → D1 x → D2 x
```